# How to use a SQL for loop to insert rows into database?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm using Postgres, and I have a large number of rows that need to be inserted into the database, that differ only in terms of an integer that is incremented.  Forgive what may be a silly question, but I'm not much of a database guru.  **Is it possible to directly enter a SQL query that will use a loop to programatically insert the rows?**

Example in pseudo-code of what I'm trying to do:

```
for i in 1..10000000 LOOP
  INSERT INTO articles VALUES(i)
end loop;
```

Comment: It'd help to know what version of PostgreSQL you're using.

Comment: You need to use a LOOP - see the examples: http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/database_guides/Practical_PostgreSQL_database/PostgreSQL_x20238_002.htm

Comment: @OMG Ponies Ouch thanks for the input. I don't suppose you could provide any pointers on the general idea of the syntax I'll need? I was looking at the loop documentation originally before posting this, which is how I ended up with that pseudo-code that I wrote in above, but I can't seem to get it into any sort of shape that Postgres seems to understand.

Comment: @William Jones: The link provides PostgreSQL syntax - your FOR loop syntax is identical.

Comment: Also, doing this is straight forward(albeit not that efficient) using a shell and the psql command line tool. Are you on a *nix ?

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Hopefully I've understood what you need (tested on 8.2):

```
INSERT INTO articles (id, name)
SELECT x.id, 'article #' || x.id
  FROM generate_series(1,10000000) AS x(id);
```

Comment: Thanks. I had to add a permission for all my roles, so I did: insert into ROLE_PERM (ROLE_ID, PERMISSION_ID)
 select ROLE_ID, 722 from ROLE order by ROLE_ID;

Comment: The most concise answer I've seen!

Answer (score 14):

In SQL Server you can do:

```
DECLARE @i int
SET @i = 1

WHILE @i<1000000
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO articles
        VALUES @i
        SET @i=@i+1
    END
```

Comment: Someone like OMGPonies can tell us if  this will work in postgre

Comment: My pgPLSQL is weak, but: http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/database_guides/Practical_PostgreSQL_database/PostgreSQL_x20238_002.htm  I'd use the recursive WITH if possible (like you see in nos' answer), but I don't have an instance to test so it looks like a loop is required (for prior to 8.4, at a minimum).  But with PostgreSQL v9 adding anonymous pgPLSQL blocks (finally, dunno how long Oracle supported), it's easier for one time use.

Answer (score 4):

Afaik, you can't write a loop directly as SQL, you'd have to create a [stored procedure](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/plpgsql.html) to do it.

This will do though (but someone can probably make it cleaner)

```
INSERT INTO articles WITH RECURSIVE i AS
(
 SELECT 1 x
  UNION ALL
 SELECT x + 1
  FROM i
 WHERE x < 10000000 
)
 SELECT x
 FROM i;
```

Comment: The [recursive WITH is 8.4+](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/queries-with.html), but there's [nothing in the documentation about supporting it in an INSERT statement](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/sql-insert.html).  That's not necessarily definitive...

Comment: OP confirmed using v8.3, can't use recursive WITH :(

Answer (score 1):

To people still visiting and want proper answer in the author's format, here is the answer.

```
do $$
begin
for i in 1..1000000 loop
insert into articles values(i);
end loop;
end;
$$;
```