# How to insert with loops in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, loops

I am trying to insert a number of rows to a table where values came from a select query

```
insert into article_rel (x_id, y_id) VALUES (12, (SELECT id from table where name = 'string')
```

this should be the same as executing this

```
insert into article_rel (x_id, y_id) VALUES (12, 1)
insert into article_rel (x_id, y_id) VALUES (12, 3)
insert into article_rel (x_id, y_id) VALUES (12, 4)
```

and so on.

I saw this [How to use a SQL for loop to insert rows into database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3764001/how-to-use-a-sql-for-loop-to-insert-rows-into-database) but I'm not sure how can this help me

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this query:

```
INSERT INTO article_rel (x_id, y_id)
  SELECT 12, id
  FROM table_name
  WHERE name = 'string'
```